# Is it possible to getText() and setTextColor() at the same time in android?

Tags: android, textview, gettext, textcolor

I want to ask, is there any textview api that we can use to `getText()` and `setTextColor()` at the same time? i mean, if in the code, it should look something like below:

`TextView.getText().equals("Hehe").setTextColor(R.color.RED);`

I appreciate any answer or suggestion here. thanks a lot!

Comment: You are applying the method `setTextColor` on a boolean and not a TextView. You definetly can't do this this way.

Comment: Probably `TextWacher` is solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. The function `equals` returns `boolean` not `TextView`.

You should try:

```
if (textView.getText().equals("Hehe")) {
  textView.setTextColor(R.color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense.

```
tv.getText().equals("Hehe")
```

returns a boolean. You cannot *SetTextColor* on a boolean.

and also

```
TextView
```

is the class, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for this:

```
textview.gettext().equals("Hehe") ? textview.setTextColor(R.color.RED) : textview.setTextColor(R.color.Green)
```

Comment: Remember to use an instance of Textview. The method you are using aren't static.